# Using type safe routes with persistent datatypes in snap

Tags: haskell, persistent, haskell-snap-framework

I have a Snap application using Persistent for storage and I'm trying to generate type safe routes for data types defined in Persistent. I'm using the [snap-web-routes package](https://github.com/lukerandall/snap-web-routes):.

I have the following Template Haskell function that creates the data type of `Group` and `GroupId`:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
  Group
    name T.Text
    deriving Show
|]
```

In my `Application.hs` I have:

```
data AppUrl = AddLink GroupId deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Generic)
```

The doc's suggest that:

```
instance PathInfo AppUrl
```

is all i need to do given the `Generic` derivation above however this blows up with

```
No instance for (PathInfo (KeyBackend SqlBackend Group))
      arising from a use of ‘Web.Routes.PathInfo.$gdmtoPathSegments’
```

My assumption is that this error indicates that Haskell does not know how to auto create the instance definition with Persistent's data types.

My next attempt was to manually define the instance:

```
instance PathInfo AppUrl where
  toPathSegments   (AddLink groupId) = "add-link" : toPathPiece groupId : []
  fromPathSegments (x:y:[]) = ????
```

I can't seem to figure out how to construct the `GroupId` data type.

From Yesod's excellent [Persistent tutorial](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) I know that the datatype is defined as:

```
type GroupId = Key Group
newtype Key Group = GroupKey (BackendKey SqlBackend)
```

But then I run into a problem because `BackendKey` is not exposed so I can't import it and create my own instance. I can't seem to find a public API to create this data type in Persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `SqlBackend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#t:SqlBackend) shows that the associated datatype  `BackendKey` is instanciated for `SqlBackend` as

```
data BackendKey SqlBackend = SqlBackendKey {
    unSqlBackendKey :: Int64
}
```

Which should be enough information to write your own `PathInfo` instance, along the lines of the following example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Database.Persist.Sql
import Data.Int (Int64)

foo :: BackendKey SqlBackend -> Int64
foo (SqlBackendKey key) = key

bar :: Int64 -> BackendKey SqlBackend
bar = SqlBackendKey
```

Comment: The data type is private to the class and not exposed so I can't actually import this.

Comment: @jvans: no, why would you think that? I've added a small example to my answer.

Comment: Ah not sure why I thought that. Must have misread an error message. Thanks for your help!